# How to combine two methods with slightly different signatures?

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following 2 methods.  The body is identical - the only difference is the 2nd parameter (Rectangle vs RectangleF) to the methods.  Is there a way to combine these 2 methods into 1 without needlessly complicating the parameter list:

```
public static void DrawRectangles(this Image thisImage, List<RectangleF> rectangles, Color color) {
  using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(thisImage)) {
    var brush = new SolidBrush(color);
    g.FillRectangles(brush, rectangles.ToArray());
  }
}

public static void DrawRectangles(this Image thisImage, List<Rectangle> rectangles, Color color) {
  using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(thisImage)) {
    var brush = new SolidBrush(color);
    g.FillRectangles(brush, rectangles.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: I guess I would wonder what benefit you would get by combining them?  Right now you can call DrawRectangles with either Rectangle or RectangleF and the compiler will choose which the correct method to call.

Comment: Use a better title .

Answer (score 3):

This is the best that I think you can do to reduce code duplication:

```
private static void DrawRectangles<T>(this Image thisImage, List<T> rectangles, Color color, Action<Graphics, Brush, T[]> fill)
{
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(thisImage))
    {
        var brush = new SolidBrush(color);
        fill(g, brush, rectangles.ToArray());
    }
}

public static void DrawRectangles(this Image thisImage, List<RectangleF> rectangles, Color color)
{
    thisImage.DrawRectangles(rectangles, color, (g, b, rs) => g.FillRectangles(b, rs));
}

public static void DrawRectangles(this Image thisImage, List<Rectangle> rectangles, Color color)
{
    thisImage.DrawRectangles(rectangles, color, (g, b, rs) => g.FillRectangles(b, rs));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `RectangleF.Implicit(Rectangle to RectangleF) Operator`, let `Rectangle` to `RectangleF` then pass be the parameter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectanglef.op_implicit?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

```
public static void DrawRectangles(this Image thisImage, List<RectangleF> rectangles, Color color)
{
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(thisImage))
    {
        var brush = new SolidBrush(color);
        g.FillRectangles(brush, rectangles.ToArray());
    }
}

public static void DrawRectangles(this Image thisImage, List<Rectangle> rectangles, Color color)
{
    var rectangleFs = rectangles.Select(x => (RectangleF) x).ToList();
    DrawRectangles(thisImage, rectangleFs, color);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a generic method which takes a generic parameters as a IEnumerable.

We then cast is as an object and gets his type either Rectangle or RectangleF. Based on that logic we then Draw the Rectangle.

```
    public static void DrawRectangles<T>(this Image thisImage, T rectangles, Color color) where T : IEnumerable
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(thisImage))
        {
            var brush = new SolidBrush(color);
            if (rectangles.Cast<object>().FirstOrDefault().GetType() == typeof(Rectangle))
            {
                g.FillRectangles(brush, rectangles.Cast<Rectangle>().ToArray());
            }
            else
            {
                g.FillRectangles(brush, rectangles.Cast<RectangleF>().ToArray());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Rectangle> r = new List<Rectangle>();
        List<RectangleF> rf = new List<RectangleF>();

        r.Add(new Rectangle(10, 10, 10, 10));
        rf.Add(new RectangleF(10.4f, 10.4f, 10.4f, 10.4f));
        DrawRectangles(new Bitmap(10, 10), rf, Color.Aqua);
    }
```

Comment: Why does the T generic parameter need to be `ref`?